# Correct grammar when listing objects with an attribute

Tags: sentence-construction, plural-forms, grammatical-number, linking-verbs, compound-subjects

I have three cars, all of them are white. I wish to form a sentence where I list the cars separately as: first, second and third, and then say they are all white. I'm unsure what is the correct form:

1. First, second and third car are white.
2. First, second and third cars are white.
3. First, second and third car is white.

I do not wish to change the structure of the sentence. Unless none of them are correct, what is the closest possible correct form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are talking about three cars that are white, it is plural.

> *The* first, second and third cars **are** white.

You could say:

> The first and second cars **are** white, and the third car **is** blue.

It may be possible to use some singular forms, but there would need to be context indicating some differences between them.